# How to use Eclipse to observe a CLion project in Git

Tags: c++, eclipse, git, cygwin, clion

There is a C/C++ project in GitLab made with CLion & Cygwin. Since I don't have CLion, I want to use Eclipse to simply look at the source files, pull updates, etc. I don't need to edit, build, or run it.

I can't figure out how to make this work. I've been able to use Eclipse to clone the repo locally, but am stuck on what to do next.

Comment: Given that you have cloned the project using `eclipse` what is preventing you from reading the source, pulling updates etc? What is your specific problem? It seems the hard part is over.

Comment: After I clone the repo, Eclipse wants me to create a project from it. Nothing I've tried works.

Comment: What I usually do is clone the git repo using `git` in the `eclipse` workespace folder. Then I go to `eclipse` and create a `C++ Makeile`project using the same name it cloned into. Then `eclipse` automatically detects the `git` control files and adds `git` features.

Comment: Thanks. Which of these options do I select for toolchain? Cross GCC, GNU Autotools, MacOSX Berkeley UPC, or MacOSX GCC? Oh, wait, there's a bunch more options if I deselect "Show only available toolchains that support this (Mac) platform".

Comment: A couple of the options mention `Cygwin`: "Cygwin GCC" and "LLVM with Clang (Windows) (Cygwin)". As I noted, the original CLion project was created on Windows using Cygwin.

Comment: I use `Makefile project->Empty project`  and `Linux GCC` tool-chain. Avoid `Cross GCC` and `GNU Autotools` unless you are cross-compiling (which you may be?) or using `GNU Autotools` (which you are not).

Comment: What system are **you** using?

Comment: MacOS High Sierra (and I don't care about compiling or editing)

Comment: Then I would  choose the simplest looking toolchain for that platform.

Comment: Probably `MacOSX GCC` (do you have `GCC` installed)?

Comment: They're part of Xcode, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the solution (after cloning the repo) is to create a new "Makefile Project with existing code". Enter the project name and point it at the local repo. In my case, for Toolchain I selected MacOSX GCC.